# Programmatically building a query with LINQ statement with entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Let's say I have a query like:

```
r = r.Where(x => iEnumerableMachineNames.Contains(x.Machine.Name) 
                 || x.Server==true);
```

Is there a way to build the predicate (I think that's what it's called) outside of the statement, for instance

```
t = (x => iEnumerableMachineNames.Contains(x.Machine.Name));
s = (x => x.Server==true)
q = t.Or(s);
r = r.Where(x => q);
```

Basically I want to programmatically build my query based on input parameters, for EF 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can build expressions dynamically but not as simply as your pseudo code - it requires reflection and expression trees ([read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx)).

A simple way to accomplish what it seems like you'd like to do is to short circuit different parts of the predicate using boolean flags:

```
bool testMachineName;
bool testIsServer;

r = r.Where( x =>
    ( !testMachineName || iEnumerableMachineNames.Contains( x.Machine.Name ) ) ||
    ( !testIsServer || x.Server ) );
```

Comment: Would that work with EF or would it complain about not being able to construct that query? I guess I'll try it... :-)

Comment: Actually that doesn't work and returns everything right? If testMachine is false it's (true || whatever) == true and returns everything... Or am I going crazy?

Comment: that's why it's `!testXyz` - if you want a specific test, the expression will evaluate to false and force the remainder of the boolean expression to evaluate.  If you don't want to test for `x.Server == true`, then you set `testIsServer = false` and that evaluates to `true`, thereby not filtering out items that are `!x.Server`